# Match all shapes that interest a single shape?

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson

I want to query which shapes intersect with the shape that has an ID of 500? I have created my mappings according to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html). My query is based on this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html). My index contains about 780 documents and was batch loaded from a file.

I create my index and mappings:

```
PUT lower_x

PUT lower_x/default/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "feature": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "geo_shape",
      "ignore_malformed": true
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

Batch load my GeoJSON successfully... My query:

```
GET lower_x/default/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "geometry": {
            "indexed_shape": {
              "index": "lower_x",
              "type": "default",
              "id": "500",
              "path": "geometry"
            },
            "relation": "intersects"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to find geo_shape field [geometry]",
        "index_uuid": "9KlMVDyIR0C5Cb1mYQr85g",
        "index": "lower_x"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "lower_x",
        "node": "FgJ4CAIjScyNtDv_Mcpn_g",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to find geo_shape field [geometry]",
          "index_uuid": "9KlMVDyIR0C5Cb1mYQr85g",
          "index": "lower_x"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 5 of elasticsearch, which does not support the `ignore_malformed` property. This was the problem.